# Returning a long value from a method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, long-integer

I looked at other posts regarding this question but none of them seems to answer a weird question. I am not sure if I am understanding the question wrong.

Return an array of `long` values from a method, use this as the return type for the method.

OPTIONS: `long, long[ ], [ ] long, long[ARRAY_SIZE]`

```
Method get()
{
   return ?
}
```

Appreciate the help, I apologize if it seems obvious but too new programmers like me it seems like a trap in choosing between `long` and `[ ]long`. I only mention those two because I am fairly positive the other 2 are invalid.

Comment: Sorry about the code format, It won't let me align it properly.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Java, I will add that to the post.

Comment: Your question is confusing.  To return a long you'd declare your method as `long myMethod() { return someLongValue; }`.

Comment: And you need to understand right away that `long[]` is an array of `long`.  If you want to return a single value you would not use `long[]`.

Answer (score 0):

The type for an array of long is:

`long[]`

There is a tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html which is worth doing if you are learning about arrays in Java.

Comment: So when returning a long array it would be: return long[ ] ;? Why not [ ] LONG?

Comment: And then couldn't you just return long?

Comment: Or are they insinuating that long is the variable name in this case?